# Netsuite Order Confirmation Email not sending

Tags: netsuite

I wanted to use an email template I constructed for Order Confirmation instead of the layout in Customize Web Site Text Customization.  I set the Web Site Setup, Email, Order Received page to select the new template.  The template did not work or contained errors, and Netsuite did not send an email for order confirmation when using this template.  I set the 'Select an Email Template' back to '- From Customize Text Group -', and now order confirmation emails are not sent at all.

Is there a setting that was modified during this process that needs to be reset?  Don't really know where to look for help on this.

Template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><html  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><![endif]-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            @import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play:400,700';
            @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
            /* Webkit styles */
            .body {
            font-family: 'Play', sans-serif !important;
            }
            .body strong {
            font-weight: 700 !important;
            }
            .body.regular strong {
            font-weight: 400 !important;
            }
            }
            @-moz-document url-prefix() {
            /* Firefox styles */
            .body {
            font-family: 'Play', sans-serif !important;
            }
            .body strong {
            font-weight: 700!important;
            }
            .body.regular strong {
            font-weight: 400 !important;
            }
            }
            @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none),  (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
            /* I.E. styles */
            .body {
            font-family: 'Play', sans-serif !important;
            }
            .body strong {
            font-weight: 700!important;
            }
            .body.regular strong {
            font-weight: 400 !important;
            }
            }
            /* Reset Styles */
            #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
            }
            body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            }
            .backgroundTable {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            }
            table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .ExternalClass * {
            line-height: 115%;
            }
            th {
            margin: 0 !important;
            font-weight: normal;
            }
            .gmail-fix {
            display: none;
            display: none!important;
            }
            /* Link Fixes */
            a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
            }
            /* All Your Font Jazz */
            /* Mobile Styles */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            /* Reset Styles */
            body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                *[class="hide"] { width: 0px !important; display: none !important; }
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG/>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body style="Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#ffffff;" >
        <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;" >

            <div class="webkit">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                <tr>
                <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="outer" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;" >
                    <!-- NAV -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="nav" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                            <tr>
                            <td width="100%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                            <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;" >
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="text-transform:uppercase; padding:22px 0 18px;"> <a href="http://www.boombah.com?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Boombah" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Boombah" width="132" border="0" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:30px; display:block"></a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table class="hide" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="body regular" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/equipment/equipment.html?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Equipment" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">EQUIPMENT</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?search_return=all&Group=Footwear&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Footwear" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">FOOTWEAR</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Gender=Men%27s&search_return=all&Shopby=New+Arrival&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Men" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">MEN</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Gender=Women%27s&search_return=all&Shopby=New+Arrival&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Women" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">WOMEN</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Shopby=New+Arrival&search_return=all&Gender=Youth&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Youth" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">YOUTH</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/custom/custom-uniforms.html?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Custom" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#636363; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">CUSTOM</strong></a> </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- END NAV -->
                </table>
                <!-- Containing Table -->
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="full-img" align="center"> <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/giveaways/soccer-uniform-giveaway.html?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Boombah Soccer Uniform Giveaway" target="_blank"><img src="images/05-17_SoccerGiveaway.jpg" alt="Boombah Soccer Uniform Giveaway" width="640" style="width:100%; max-width:640px; padding-bottom:30px;" border="0" style="display:block"></a> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>            
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #c3c3c3; border-top: 2px solid #c3c3c3;">
                            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                        <!-- Navigation -->
                                        <table class="hide" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="body regular" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/equipment/equipment.html?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Equipment" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">EQUIPMENT</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?search_return=all&Group=Footwear&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Footwear" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">FOOTWEAR</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Gender=Men%27s&search_return=all&Shopby=New+Arrival&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Men" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">MEN</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Gender=Women%27s&search_return=all&Shopby=New+Arrival&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Women" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">WOMEN</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/shop.html?Shopby=New+Arrival&search_return=all&Gender=Youth&utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Youth" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">YOUTH</strong></a> &nbsp; <a href="http://www.boombah.com/us/custom/custom-uniforms.html?utm_source=USSSA&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=05-17_SoccerGiveaway" title="Custom" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px; color:#c3c3c3; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap; padding:14px; border:1px solid #ffffff; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;"><strong style="font-weight:normal;">CUSTOM</strong></a> </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- Navigation END -->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#e1e1e1" align="center">
                            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;max-width:640px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="padding:50px 40px;">
                                        <!-- Headline -->
                                        <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="pad-lr-20 copy-21 body" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; color:#939393; text-align:center; text-transform: uppercase; padding:0 0 25px;">CONNECT WITH BOOMBAH</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- Headline END -->
                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="" align="center" style="padding: 0 0 40px; border-bottom:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
                                                    <!-- Social Icons -->
                                                    <table class="full-width" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding:0 12px;"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BoombahInc/" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.gif" width="35" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;"></a> </td>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding:0 12px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/boombahinc/" title="Instagram" target="_blank"><img src="images/instagram.gif" width="35" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;"></a> </td>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding:0 12px;"> <a href="https://twitter.com/boombahinc" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.gif" width="35" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;"></a> </td>
                                                                <td align="center" style="padding:0 12px;"> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/BoombahInc" title="YouTube" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.gif" width="35" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;"></a> </td>                                                                 
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <!-- Social Icons END-->
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>                                            
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            <![endif]-->
            </div>


        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you show the custom email template that you have?

Comment: Answer:  Setup > Company > Email preferences, Email Options tab was set to 'Do not send emails', the errors in the HTML template must have flipped this switch.